# Denied Exchange 2016's ECP access from internet

Tags: exchange-2016

I'm using Exchange 2016 in my production and I want to denied ECP access from external (internet). How can I do it and where should be configure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use IIS.

First add “IP and Domain Restrictions” feature in IIS. “`Install-WindowsFeature Web-IP-Security`”

Then in the IIS management,  go to ECP directory, only allow the internal IP address rang.

You could refer to this article for more detailed information:
http://msexchangeguru.com/2016/09/10/e2016-deny-external-eac/